# Probability density function of a function of a uniform random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose that a random variable $X$ has a uniform distribution over the interval (0,1) i.e. $X$~U(0,1). Let $Y$ be a random variable such that $Y$ = |$X$-1/3|. What is the probability density function of $Y$?

How can this be solved?

Comment: have you tried to just plot the new distribution function?

Answer (score 0):

Just observe that - for example by plotting the distribution function of $Y$ - that we have first
$$
Y\in(0,\frac23) \text{ simply because }X\sim U(0,1),X\in(0,1)
$$
and therefore
$$
F_Y(y)=\begin{cases}0,y\leq0 \\2y,0< y\leq\frac13 \\ y+\frac13,\frac13\leq y<\frac23 \\ 1,y\geq\frac23  \end{cases}
$$
whch gives us the density function by a piecewise derivative as well
$$
f_Y(y)=\begin{cases}0,y\leq0 \\2,0< y\leq\frac13 \\ 1,\frac13\leq y<\frac23 \\ 0,y\geq\frac23  \end{cases}
$$
So the steps are really

- how does $Y$ looks like, plot
- use the properties of $X$ distribution to find the cdf of $Y$
- simply compute the derivative (piecewise) and glue together